# In textView when I click on done button the keyboard is not resigning

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm getting problem in resigning the keyboard after clicking done button. I'm using textView

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(textView == addressView)
    {
        if(isNotif)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
        }
        textView.text= [textView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        [addressView resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Instead of keyboard resigning the cursor is coming to new line in the text field.
Please help me.

Thank You
Praveena.

Comment: There is no such delegate -(BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following delegate

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (textView == YourTextField){
        if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
                [textView resignFirstResponder];
                return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Usually in textView the return key is use to add \n to the text, so its better to add some other button to top of the UItextView and code the resigning function there.

**EDIT:**

There is no such delegate `-(BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textView`

Comment: make sure you have set the delegate

Comment: how this is an answer, this code hides keyboard on any character input!

Answer (score 5):

Fixed KingOfBliss's answer:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{       
    if (textView == messageInput) {
        if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
            [textView resignFirstResponder];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this will happen if the ViewController that is above this textView in the view hierarchy is not the delegate of this textView.  If it is not then the ViewController will never get the message textViewShouldReturn. In the viewController after the subView (the UITextView) is created.

```
aTextView.delegate = self;
```

To check to make sure it is getting called add this to your function and test

```
NSLog(@"resigning first responder");
```

this will test to see if this function is even getting called

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
```

was enough in my case.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.