# How to click UIButton when user hits return on keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uibutton

I want to be able to send a message as soon as the user touches return on the on-screen keyboard.  I have a send UIButton, how do I make it listen for the return key?
Thanks!

Comment: TextField or TextView?

Comment: You don't click a button when the user taps return on the keyboard. You simply have both events call the same method.

Comment: Ok, updated for textField!

Answer (score 1):

Your button Method:

```
- (void) btnPressed:(id)sender {

{
```

Add Delegate Stuff if you haven't

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

And when you call your textField:

```
yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

Then, you should just call the button's action method in the delegate `shouldReturn` method:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [self btnPressed:nil];
    // whatever else you need

    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook `textFieldShouldReturn:` and send a message to the button or directly to the function that button calls.

If you're using `UITextView`, [it takes a bit of trickery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862466/in-textview-when-i-click-on-done-button-the-keyboard-is-not-resigning):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{       
    if (textView == messageInput) {
        if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
            // your code goes here
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```